# Refused to get "Unsafe Header - Location" while getting response header in item service

Tags: sitecore-services-client

I'm trying to create an item using `ItemService` in `Sitecore.Services.Client`.

Item creation is working fine and response looks like this:

> 201 (Created).
>
> Location: /item/0727f965-2338-43cc-bd88-5071ad3f7a12?database=master

My need is to get this location in the response header.

During that I'm facing this issue:

> refused to get unsafe header "Location" Error

Below is attached my code sample:

```
 request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'Location');
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    console.log(this.status); 
                    console.log(this.getResponseHeader('Location'));                                       
                }
            };
```

Comment: Have you tried `request.getResponseHeader('Location')`? or `request.getAllResponseHeaders();`?

Comment: both i tried.
for request.getAllResponseHeaders(); - i get only simple request headers like cache control,expires etc
for request.getResponseHeader('Location') -i'm getting error

Comment: It looks like this may be caused by Cross Domain Resource Sharing limitations https://stackoverflow.com/a/5837798/157833

Comment: if this so, where i pass this web.config ? or sitecore.services.client.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by using the below code in web.config

```
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="*"/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```